# Display glitch after power outage

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, display

I installed Arch and Gnome which was working fine for couple of days.

Today the laptop got suddenly turned off because of a power outage( battery is dead for quite sometime, only lasts for few minutes. Now when I turn on the laptop, it has weird white dots on black screen, blinking.

Image[image]:

Please help me to fix it or let me know how to debug this.

Edit:

I cannot proceed further with the dots.

Live USB works fine without dots.

The dots seems to related to terminal. Typing adds more dots. Typing command `clear` blindly and hit enter clears the dots.

Comment: Does the laptop boot correctly or is that the only thing you see? Do the dots ever leave? Have you tried booting another operating system (booting from a live USB or CD)?

Comment: Question edited. Please check.